# VisualForce parsing the script and replacing regular expressions

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have some script to denormalize the tags that get normalized in the Ajax return. The problem is that when I do: `str.replace( /&amp;/g, "&" )` in my script, the VisualForce page rendering alters the string to be: `str.replace( /&#38;/g, "&" )`. It's not at all the same thing. Is there a way to keep the VisualForce page rendering from altering my script when it translates the page?

This may be the answer, I probably should change it to a resource and just add a reference to the separate script file. The trouble with this is that changing a debugging the script will be painful because I'll have to keep reloading the resource every time I make a change. I was planning on doing this later but during the development phase, this will be painful.

Comment: It's not clear from your posting what the different is, both str.replace calls look identical.  Typo?

Comment: Stack Exchanged rendered both the `&amp;` and `&#38;` as `&` in the original question because they weren't included in in-line code marks (`\``).

Comment: Looks like I should have enclosed the post in code tags because it has been normalized to the point the code has been removed. I put the script and style sheets in a resource within my org but now the Ajax code is broken and I'm not sure why. All I did is remove my javascript from the page and place it in a resource. Now when I try to invoke the remote method, the VF Ajax handler fails with the exception of "b is undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use this insead:

```
str.replace( /{!HTMLENCODE('&')}/g, '&' );
```

The [`HTMLENCODE`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_variables_functions.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_variables_functions.htm|SkinName=webhelp) visualforce function will encode the ampersand (`&`) into `&amp;` on the server-side when the page is loaded.

In the page source, it will appear as:

```
str.replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );
```

Comment: Where should I have found that information? I'm sure there is much more there I could find useful.

Comment: It's in the [Visualforce documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_variables_functions.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_variables_functions.htm|SkinName=webhelp).